# proper use of 'that' demonstrative

Tags: grammar, that

I'm confused about how to use the 'that' demonstrative in the following sentence:

> Finally, in Part 4 we analysed **the results that obtained** in the parts mentioned above, and we showed **further experiments we have done** to contribute to the topics of those parts.

In the first bold clause, I used `that` because `results` is defined in the context before. And in the second bold clause, I didn't use `that` after the word `experiments` because `further experiments` were not defined.

Is this correct?

Comment: Using "that obtained", without a subject, is sometimes seen in technical writing but is a little weird.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean exactly by a subject?

Comment: Subject/verb/object.

Comment: What do you mean by the "that" preposition? "That" is not a preposition.

Comment: @HotLicks but if I do `we analysed the results that we obtained` it seems redundant, no?

Comment: @IsabelArcher, you're right .. I thought that it's a preposition. The question updated.

Comment: You could say "that was obtained".

Comment: @HotLicks, but what about my question? is it correct that way I used it?

Comment: @Ghanem - It's not idiomatic in the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Obtained* has a slightly different meaning with and without an object. From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/obtain):

> VERB
>
> 1 *[with object]* Get, acquire, or secure (something)
>
> ‘adequate insurance cover is difficult to obtain’
>
> 2 *formal [no object]* Be prevalent, customary, or established.
>
> ‘the price of silver fell to that obtaining elsewhere in the ancient
>   world’

In the sentence as written *that* introduces a relative clause where the understood stubject is *results* and the definition of *obtain* would be number 2 from above.

If you wanted to use *obtain* with definition 1 from above, you'd have to change your sentence so that *obtained* is in the passive:

...*the results obtained...*

...*the results that were obtained...*

Comment: Thanks!, what about part 2 of the question?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the second part as is. You could add in _that_ without changing the meaninng one bit. As it stands now it's a bare relative - one that does not have a realtive word or _that_ to introduce the relative clause. If you added a relative word in, the meaning wouldn't change _further experiments **which/that** we have done_

Comment: Thank you again.